# Name for 16⊕1͞6 bosons of E6 & larger GUTs?

Tags: terminology, group-theory, representation-theory, grand-unification

[E<sub>6</sub> GUTs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.1049) put fermions into $27→16_1⊕10_{-2}⊕1_4$ and gauge bosons into $78→45_0⊕16_{-3}⊕\overline{16}_{3}⊕1_0$. And larger GUTs (e.g. [E<sub>8</sub> on ⁶/ℤ₆×ℤ₂](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.13248), [E<sub>8</sub> on ⁶/ℤ₃×ℤ₃](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.05495)) usually incorporate these.

The $16_1$ and $45_0$ are the SM fermions and Spin(10) gauge bosons. Supersymmetric models often identify $10_{-2}$ with Higgs doublets+triplets (sometimes also as vector-like fermions).  And the $1_4$ has been termed a ["flavon" (φ) or "flavlet."](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.05495)

Are there standard, common, or even uncommon or proposed names in the literature for the $16_{-3}⊕\overline{16}_{3}$ particles (almost an exotic generation)?